# Rspec bundle is broken in TextMate and rvm

Tags: ruby, rspec, textmate, rvm

I've had a difficult time since I started using rvm.  I've done all the rvm/textmate set up and have the latest bundles but **I still can't run Rspec test from textmate**.

- I have the latest bundle from `github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle.git`
  and it's installed in `~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
   RSpec.tmbundle`
- RVM default is using the system ruby 1.8.6
- Rspec gem versions

  gem list --local | grep spec
  blue_light_special (0.2.0)
  rspec (2.2.0)
  rspec-core (2.2.1, 2.0.1)
  rspec-expectations (2.2.0, 2.0.1)
  rspec-mocks (2.2.0, 2.0.1)
  rspec-rails (2.0.1, 1.3.2)
- TextMate

  TM_RUBY=/Users/jspooner/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
- The Error: **rspec/core (LoadError)**

  /Users/jspooner/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/rspec/mate.rb:29:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec/core (LoadError) from /Users/jspooner/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/rspec/mate.rb:29 from /tmp/textmate-command-8073.rb:2:in`require' from /tmp/textmate-command-8073.rb:2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution I've found is from Jacques Crocker.
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/64b84bbcdf49e9b?fwc=1

It requires replacing the contents of textmate_ruby with the code below and never running rvm wrapper xxx textmate again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh 
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
cd . 
exec ruby "$@"
```

This has also fixed the same issue with the cucumber bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following the instructions here: http://rvm.io/integration/textmate/

Comment: Okay I found the problem with those directions.  In text it says to set TM_RUBY to /Users/wayne/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby and in the image (http://cl.ly/23Yl) it shows it set to rvm-auto-ruby.

textmate_ruby works and the rvm-auto-ruby doesn't work.

Comment: @jspooner, how about sending a note to Wayne Seguin, who wrote and maintains RVM, and let him know about the error. Do `rvm -v` for his email address. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

My case is slightly different but took me more than an hour to figure out:

Turns out I ran `rvm wrapper ree textmate` a while after installing ree with rvm and in the mean time the **ree** shorthand changed from meaning `ree-1.8.7-2010.01` to `ree-1.8.7-2010.02`

here's more details on my message:
https://gist.github.com/721987

*I'm posting it here too because it's one of the first pages I landed onto while trying to figure this one out.*

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem and figured out that my textmate ruby wrapper is pointing to a different version. I was able to get it work by putting below content in projectx/.rvmrc

rvm 1.9.2@projectx --create

rvm wrapper 1.9.2@projectx textmate

Hope this helps.