# TextMate, rvm and TM_RUBY

Tags: ruby, textmate, rvm

In the [TextMate RVM instructions](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/) the text it says to set `TM_RUBY` to `/Users/wayne/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby` and in [the image](http://cl.ly/23Yl) it shows it set to `rvm-auto-ruby`.  I decided to set it to `rvm-auto-ruby` thinking that it would use RVM's default Ruby version.

When running `Command R` in the RSpec.bundle having `TM_RUBY` set to `rvm-auto-ruby` will result in a [load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317200/rspec-bundle-is-broken-in-textmate-and-rvm).  When you set it to `textmate_ruby` it works.

The only problem here is that TextMate doesn't always use the default version of Ruby since it's hardcoded in that file.

`/Users/jspooner/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/Users/jspooner/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-head" ]] ; then
  source "/Users/jspooner/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-head"
  exec ruby "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/jspooner/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-head'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

So two questions:

1. What should `TM_RUBY=rvm-auto-ruby` actually do?
2. Is there a way to have TextMate use the RVM default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See your other, similar, question [Rspec bundle is broken in TextMate and rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317200/rspec-bundle-is-broken-in-textmate-and-rvm).

---

To help others chasing this same issue, the solution seems to be at: [RVM / Textmate doesnt recognize .rvmrc Options](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/64b84bbcdf49e9b?fwc=1).

Basically you replace the `~/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby` soft link with a file. This is what I did:

1. `cd ~/.rvm/bin`
2. `mv textmate_ruby old.textmate_ruby`
3. Create a shell script called `textmate_ruby` in the same directory to replace the soft-link, using the following contents:

   ```
   !/usr/bin/env sh

   source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
   cd . 
   exec ruby "$@"
   ```
4. `chmod +x textmate_ruby`

Before doing this change I'd see my system Ruby's version (1.8.7) displayed if I did <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to run the following script in TextMate:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Evaluating the script using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>CNTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> gave me 1.9.2.

After switching to use that script both point to Ruby 1.9.2, so at least there's some consistency now. I don't see TextMate tracking my currently set RVM Ruby version yet; Instead it's using the default version set in RVM: `rvm use 1.9.2 --default`. This is still a step forward because I can control which Ruby TextMate uses by adjusting my `--default`.

If you decide you want to revert later, just rename, or delete, the script and reverse step 2 above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I had to delete the `PATH` shell variable from TextMate as well.  Not sure how this was interacting or why I'd put it there previously (can't remember) but removing it helped.

Answer (score 10):

Setting TM_RUBY to `your-path/rvm-auto-ruby`

http://rvm.io/integration/textmate/

should load whatever ruby and gemset is indicated in the .rvmrc file located in the project and if none default to rvm default.  I just got this working and it is very smooth. I did need to get the latest version of rvm

```
rvm get head
```

to make it work and restart Textmate.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep your correct.  This post is quite old and since then I've been using this method.

Comment: You can also append `/Users/username/.rvm/bin` to your TextMate `PATH` and then simply use `rvm-auto-ruby` as your `TM_RUBY`

Comment: this doesn't help with gem executables though